# Remove String from column based on character

Tags: mysql

i have table :

table : mytable

```
id  name
1   abcd ( dljdf
2   kjlkjkldjf ( ( ( ;dfld )
```

I want to remove string starting from character '('.

Result would look like

```
id  name
1   abcd
2   kjlkjkldjf
```

I tried using [Trim](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) Function but it did not give me required result

Any help plz.

Comment: Everything you need can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '(', 1) FROM test;

UPDATE test
    SET name = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '(', 1));
```

(assuming you want to get rid of the space, too)

Answer (score 0):

To peform this task, I did the following

Created my table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, name VARCHAR(25));
```

Inserted test data:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'abcd ( dljdf');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'kjlkjkldjf ( ( ( ;dfld )');
```

Then, using the [SUBSTRING function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and the [LOCATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), I ran this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, (LOCATE(' ', name) - 1)) AS MyResult FROM test;
```

Result:

```
MyResult
---------
abcd
kjlkjkldjf
```

If you wish to include the blank between the end of the first alphabetical string and the left bracket, substitute `(` for  (space) in the locate part of the above query. If this isn't suitable, please expand on your requirements.